# "File not found" trying to listdir() a path dragged-and-dropped from Finder to terminal in Python

Tags: python, macos

after researching this error the solution most suggested is to use absolute path instead of relative (which makes sense and obvious)
however this doesnt work in macos.
and I thought python works on all platforms the same
my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
directory = input("insert path: ")
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        print(f)
```

once I run this I get a prompt asking me to insert the directory path. so I drag and drop the directory and the absolute path is inserted.
right after I hit enter. I get the famous error file or directory not found.
any help ?

Comment: Python is platform independent definitely. and the same code you have used works for me absolutely fine. If you are doing a pwd on the directory and then giving it as an input to this it should be working fine. Remember the directory path always starts with a '/'

Comment: What do you see if you do `print(repr(f))` in the loop?

Comment: It's not clear from the original title or body of the question what the specific technical problem you're asking about is -- with the prior title, one needed to read the answer to fully/properly understand the question. I've tried to fix that, but please feel encouraged to [edit] further to improve the question's descriptiveness.

Comment: Also, the question would have been **much** stronger if you'd showed the content of the `directory` variable after this operation was performed -- then it would be obvious to someone reading _why_ you had this error, permitting better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code and drag a folder from finder into the (iterm2) terminal window, it inserts a space after the path, probably to be helpful in case you want to pass other arguments to a shell, which would be space separated. Remove the space manually before hitting enter, and it should work.

When the path you drag in has spaces, Finder seems to try to quote these spaces, e.g., `foo bar` becomes `foo\ bar`. Again this makes sense for a shell, where spaces can be escaped like this, but your Python program is not a shell, so you'd check for `\`  and replace it with a plain   again:

```py
directory = directory.replace(r"\ ", " ")
```

And if you want to do that kind of processing, you could also remove the trailing space for better usability:

```
directory = directory.strip()
```

Comment: thank you. it did work eventually. however if the directory name has spaces like: "my directory" it will not work no matter what even if I wrap the name with double quotes. it worked after changing the dir name to a single word

Comment: @AmineTbaik I've added code to deal with spaces in file names